# `blur()` is not working perfectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, blur

I've created a simple program which will get data and validate it server side in vb.net's default validators.

For first time its working perfactly. But in the second time, doing the same thing, blur event of `txtDOB` is not being called.

My codes are as below:

### .ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Test_NET_27.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test_NET_27" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>.NET Test</title>

    <script src="Script/Jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Script/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="Script/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="background-color: Silver; height: 600px; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%;
        margin-top: 2%">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <fieldset style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 10%">
            <legend style="text-align: Left; font-size: medium;"><strong>User Details </strong>
            </legend>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline"
                ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div align="center">
                        <table style="width: auto; max-width: 100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="100%" style="text-align: right">
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl" Text="* Fields are Mandatory." ForeColor="red"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: right">
                                    <strong style="font-size: small">Name<label style="color: Red">*</label>
                                        :</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" placeholder="Enter Name" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <div>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Name!"
                                            ControlToValidate="txtName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Text Only!"
                                            ControlToValidate="txtName" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]*$">
                                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: right">
                                    <strong style="font-size: small">DOB<label style="color: Red">*</label>
                                        :</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Block">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDOB" placeholder="e.g.: 28-Oct-1989" TabIndex="2"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calDOB" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDOB" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy">
                                            </cc1:CalendarExtender>
                                            <div>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorDOB" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Enter DOB!"
                                                    ControlToValidate="txtDOB"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgeDob" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDOB"
                                                    ErrorMessage="Please enter DOB in dd-mmm-yyyy format" SetFocusOnError="True"
                                                    ValidationExpression="^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\-\d{4}$"
                                                    Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                            </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="text-align: right">
                                                <strong style="font-size: small">Age :</strong>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="text-align: left">
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAge"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <%--<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAge"></asp:Label>--%>
                                            </td>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: right">
                                    <strong style="font-size: small">Group<label style="color: Red">*</label>
                                        :</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: left">
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGroup" TabIndex="3" AutoPostBack="True">
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Value</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Gold</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Silver</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Bronze</asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                    <div>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator_ddlGroup" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select Group!"
                                            ControlToValidate="ddlGroup" Display="Dynamic" SetFocusOnError="True" InitialValue="0">
                                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="text-align: Left">
                                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkActive" Text="Active" TabIndex="4" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <%--<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"  />--%>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="100%" align="center">
                                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" Text="ADD" TabIndex="5" OnClientClick="return fnValidate();" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvDetails" Style="width: 100%;" align="center" CellPadding="4"
                                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" Wrap="true" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" Wrap="true" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Group" HeaderText="Group">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" Wrap="true" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" Wrap="true" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" Wrap="true" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" Wrap="true" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" Wrap="true" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" Wrap="true" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Operation">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/remove.png" Height="15px"
                                                    Width="15px" ToolTip="Delete" TabIndex="6" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Row?');" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="7%" Wrap="true" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="7%" Wrap="true" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </fieldset>
        <%--<div style="width: 60%; margin-left: 20%; margin-right: 10%">
            <fieldset>
                <legend style="text-align: Left; font-size: medium;"><strong>Saved Details </strong>
                </legend>

            </fieldset>
        </div>--%>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //        var username = new Array();
        //        var len = username.length;
        $("#txtDOB").blur(function() {
            debugger;
            var content = {};
            content.dob = $("#txtDOB").val().toString();
            var jsonText = JSON.stringify(content);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Test_NET_27.aspx/GetAge",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                data: jsonText,
                success: function(data) {
                    debugger;
                    var dataget = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                    $("#txtAge").val(dataget[0].age);
                },
                error: function(ex) {
                    alert("Error Occured While Calculating Age! : " + ex);
                }
            });
        });

        function fnValidate() {

            if ($("#txtName").val() == "") {
                alert("Please Enter UserName");
                $("#txtName").focus();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                var alphaValidate = /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/;
                if (!alphaValidate.test($("#txtName").val())) {
                    alert("Please Enter Only Text in User Name");
                    $("#txtName").val() = "";
                    $("#txtName").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (jQuery.inArray($("#txtName").val().toUpperCase(), username) == 0) {
                alert("Please Enter Unique UserName.");
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#txtDOB").val() == "") {
                alert("Please Enter Birth Date.");
                return false;
            }
            if ($("#ddlGroup option:selected").val() == 0) {
                alert("Please Select Group!");
                $("#ddlGroup").focus();
                return false;
            }
            //username[len] = $("#txtName").val().toUpperCase();
            return false;
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### VB

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Data

Partial Class Test_NET_27
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


#Region "Variables"
    Private VS_Grid As String = "Null"
#End Region

#Region "PageEvents"
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.txtAge.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly")
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "Button Event"
    Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim dt_grid As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Try

            If Not Page.IsValid Then
                Me.Validate()
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If (Me.ViewState(VS_Grid) Is Nothing) Then
                dt_grid.Columns.Add("Name")
                dt_grid.Columns.Add("Group")
                dt_grid.Columns.Add("Active")
                dt_grid.Columns.Add("Age")
                'dt_grid.Columns.Add("Operation")
            Else
                dt_grid = Me.ViewState(VS_Grid)
            End If
            dr = dt_grid.NewRow
            dr("Name") = Me.txtName.Text.ToString.Trim
            dr("Group") = Me.ddlGroup.SelectedItem.Text.ToString.Trim
            dr("Active") = "InActive"
            If Me.chkActive.Checked = True Then
                dr("Active") = "Active"
            End If
            dr("Age") = Me.txtAge.Text.ToString.Trim

            dt_grid.Rows.Add(dr)
            Me.ViewState(VS_Grid) = dt_grid
            If dt_grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Me.gvDetails.DataSource = dt_grid
                Me.gvDetails.DataBind()
            Else
                Me.gvDetails.EmptyDataText = "No Data Available."
                Me.gvDetails.DataSource = Nothing
                Me.gvDetails.DataBind()
            End If
            fnResetValues()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
#End Region

#Region "GridEvents"
    Protected Sub gvDetails_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvDetails.RowCommand
        Dim index As Integer = e.CommandArgument
        Dim dt_grid As New DataTable
        Try
            dt_grid = Me.ViewState(VS_Grid)
            If dt_grid.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                If e.CommandName.ToUpper = "DELETE" Then
                    dt_grid.Rows(index).Delete()

                End If
                dt_grid.AcceptChanges()
                Me.ViewState(VS_Grid) = dt_grid
                Me.gvDetails.DataSource = dt_grid
                Me.gvDetails.DataBind()
                Me.UpdatePanel2.Update()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvDetails_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvDetails.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            CType(e.Row.FindControl("lnkDelete"), ImageButton).CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex
            CType(e.Row.FindControl("lnkDelete"), ImageButton).CommandName = "DELETE"
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvDetails_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles gvDetails.RowDeleting

    End Sub

#End Region

#Region "WebMethod"
    <Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
        Public Shared Function GetAge(ByVal dob As String) As String

        Dim dt_jsonData As New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt_jsonData.NewRow
        Dim age As Integer
        Dim jsonString As String = String.Empty
        Try
            age = Math.Floor(DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateValue(dob), Now()) / 12)
            dt_jsonData.Columns.Add("age")
            dr("age") = age.ToString.Trim()
            dt_jsonData.Rows.Add(dr)
            If dt_jsonData.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt_jsonData)
            End If
            Return jsonString
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return ""
            Exit Function
        End Try
    End Function
#End Region

#Region "Reset Values"
    Public Function fnResetValues() As Boolean
        Me.txtName.Text = ""
        Me.txtDOB.Text = ""
        Me.txtAge.Text = ""
        Me.ddlGroup.SelectedValue = 0
        Me.chkActive.Checked = False
    End Function
#End Region

End Class
```

And also in `javascript`'s `fnValidate()` when I'm removing

```
if (jQuery.inArray($("#txtName").val().toUpperCase(), username) == 0) {
                alert("Please Enter Unique UserName.");
                return false;
}
```

`btnADD`'s click event in VB side is not executed.

Comment: Instead of posting reams of untestable code, post a little bit of relevant code and a jsfiddle.net that shows the issue

Comment: but my main code is VB side, and i guess `jsfiddle` might not support that.

Comment: The blur is client side, so post the rendered HTML that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep this in mind next time. But this time I've posted the whole code. Please bare with it.

Comment: How can I? I am not going to create a VB project and run it to see where it is not working or try to eyeball all this? YOU have the problem, YOU do the work that enables us to help you. BUT start by removing TWO of the jQuery libraries you load.

Comment: The reason I posted the whole HTML is because I've used update panels in this. It might possible that it may generate this problem.

But though, thank you for your support.

Comment: Look in Chrome and the net tab to see if the post is being triggered at all

Comment: Jquery.Js, Jquery.min.js and Jquery-1.9.1.js, Including more than one jQuery in your site does not do you any good. You are doing it wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I've removed those. But the problem is still occurring.

Comment: mplungjan : I've tried it. Its working correct for first time. But in the same scenario, when one row is added to `gridview`, after selecting the `DOB` `.blur()` is not executing even a single time.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove all but ONE jQuery library
2. You do not have UNIQUE IDs when you add rows. Change ID="txtDOB" to class="txtDOB" and similar for other fields with ID

Change your code to something like

```
 $("#UpdatePanel3").on("blur",".txtDOB",function() { 
        debugger;
        var content = {"dob": $(this).val()};
        var jsonText = JSON.stringify(content);
```

Comment: Well, I tried this. But still its not calling `blur` event second time. Can we apply bind to `txtDOB` on `pageLoad`? Is it possible that second time this trick may work?

Comment: then you need to debug. We cannot do that for you. My suggestion is definitely valid so check your "inspect element" to see you actually implement what I suggest

Answer (score 0):

It's done!!!

All I needed to do is add `onblur` in `textbox` and I modify the blur event in function. i.e.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDOB" placeholder="e.g.: 28-Oct-1989" TabIndex="2"
onblur="blurFunction();"></asp:TextBox>


function blurFunction() {
            debugger;
            var content = {};
            content.dob = $("#txtDOB").val().toString();
            var jsonText = JSON.stringify(content);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Test_NET_27.aspx/GetAge",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                data: jsonText,
                success: function(data) {
                    debugger;
                    var dataget = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                    $("#txtAge").val(dataget[0].age);
                },
                error: function(ex) {
                    alert("Error Occured While Calculating Age! : " + ex);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: And you get the value of each field correctly??? at least pass (this) to the function and use passedField.value inside the function

Comment: No needed for that. I got each value perfectly with my solution.